# Call soap webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap, https

i have a console application which calls a php soap webserivice via http which has been working fine for the past few years.
Now I switched to https but updating the webservice in Visual Studio on calling it I always get the error: Request canceled: Could not create SSL / TLS secure channel.
I re-imported the webservice in Visual Studio with "Add Service Reference" providing the webservice address with ?wsdl and it finds it correctly with all methods.
On the code side I instantiate the web service and call the method, as I did before in http:

ServiceReference2.serverPortTypeClient service = new ServiceReference2.serverPortTypeClient("serverPort1");
string res = service.getOrder();

I can't figure out if the problem is in the call or server side.
Do I need to add code to somehow handle SSL?

Thank you

Comment: Concrete answer depends on .net version, have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-a-net-framework-version-earlier-than-47

Comment: @pakeha_by thank you, after update to Fx 4.8 on call webservice the error change in The server returned an invalid SOAP error. Could not find element 'faultstring' with namespace name ''.